# Unable to replace variable in shell script using awk

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have been struggling to replace every occurence of "`<KEY>`" in a file with `${encryptedkeyValue}`                                                             I wrote this line but it is not doing anything. please help

```
awk ' { gsub("<KEY>","'${encryptedkeyValue}'") }1 ' ${scriptHome}/config.properties
```

Thanks in advance,
Priya

Comment: I see in your raw posting that you want to replace a KEY string. (I edited your posting, but you should confirm or correct it.) Please clarify whether the `<` and `>` and two `"` are part of the `KEY` keyword. I then adjust my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to replace a string consisting of two double quotes, and also pass your variables using option `-v`, as in:

```
awk -v val="${encryptedkeyValue}" '{ gsub(/<KEY>/,val) } 1'
```